# Se eu quiser criar uma API com os dados existentes aqui do Stack Overflow, poderia legalmente fazer isso?

Tags: debate, api

Pergunto isso pois me surgiu uma ideia de utilizar os dados (perguntas e respostas) que transitam aqui e criar uma API sem fins lucrativos em cima desses dados.

A minha dúvida é se legalmente eu posso fazer isso, visto que os dados são abertos mas para pegá-los de forma automatizada temos de criar um *crawler* por exemplo.

Pelo que eu saiba não existe um banco de dados aberto à comunidade para utilizar esses dados e quem sabe criar-se APIs em cima dessa maravilhosa ferramenta que é o SO.

Comment: Se pode ou não eu não sei, vou deixar pro Gabe responder de maneira oficial. O conteúdo das perguntas e respostas é Creative Commons. E existe sim uma [**API**](https://api.stackexchange.com/), bem como [**dumps periódicos da base de dados**](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), e uma ferramenta para consulta dos dados usando SQL, o [**data explorer**](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @bfavaretto, acho que se somar CreativeCommons + API + SEDE resulta em "não é ilegal e o sistema oferece ferramentas para isso". Mas, sim, melhor deixar a gerência responder.

Comment: Na verdade, é só ler a página http://stackexchange.com/legal para obter uma resposta. O mais indicado seria passar para um advogado dar um parecer. Aliás, caro CM, não seria o caso de ter uma tradução dessa página?

Comment: Raul, confira o tipo de Apps que o pessoal faz usando a API em [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/)

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações brasofilo e bfavaretto .
Essas infos já dão uma boa direção.
+1 para os dois pelos apontamentos.